# Determine values of coefficients of a linear homogeneous second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y''+ay'+by=0$.
>
> 1) Find values of $a,b$ such that all the solutions are bounded on
>   $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> 2) Find values of $a,b$ such that there exists a solution which is not
>   bounded, and which attains the value $0$ infinite number of times
>   (that is - there are infinitely many points $x_0$ such that
>   $y(x_0)=0$).
>
> 3) Find a necessary and a sufficient condition on $a,b$ values so
>   that one of the basis vectors of the solution vector space will have the
>   property $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(y(x)\exp\left({\frac{ax}{2}}\right )
>  \right )=0$$ 
>   while the second basis vector will have the property
>   $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(y(x)\exp\left({\frac{ax}{2}}\right ) \right )=0$$

My attempt:

1) None, because the solutions are always proportional to $e^{\lambda x}$ which is not bounded.

2) All the values of $a,b$ for which the roots of the equation $\lambda^2+a\lambda+b=0$ are complex ($a^2-4b<0$). In this case the solution has the form $e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)$ which has infinitely many intersections with the $x$-axis. Also, these solutions are not bounded due to the $e^{\alpha x}$ factor.

3) Can't really find. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that sinusoids are bounded

Comment: Note that davyjones comment to get a more precise answer for your parts 1 and 2.  For part 3: What if you consider the case of purely real solutions?  Also, are there any cases of complex solutions that work?